# Error :"Imported content is empty" in importhtml function in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula

I want fetch the table details from https://www.edelweiss.in/market/nse-option-chain in a gogle sheet, I had used the formula
`=IMPORTHTML("https://www.edelweiss.in/market/nse-option-chain","table",1)` , but getting the empty error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data to Google Sheets from a website that uses JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237688/scraping-data-to-google-sheets-from-a-website-that-uses-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `=IMPORTHTML` cannot be used because the website you're trying to get the data from load the data **dynamically**.

#### Possible solution

A possible solution to gather the data might be found if you follow these steps:

*1. Identify the the URL that is making the request with the data you want*

You can do this by using the Google Chrome Console and checking the `Network Tab` and filtering the requests by `XHR`.

*2. Import the `IMPORTJSON` library and use Apps Script*

Install the library by accessing this link [here](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON). You should install the library by using Apps Script and going to `Tools` -> `Script Editor` -> add the `ImportJSON.gs`.

*3. Use the formula in your Sheet*

You could use the formula like this:

```
=ImportJSON("THE_LINK_FOUND_AT_STEP_1")
```

**Reference**

- [ImportJSON Library](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON)

Comment: Tried , but getting the desired result .. I need the table data